# How can I download large files from Google Drive?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-drive

I uploaded a file on Google Drive, which is 1.3 GB in size.
Now when I try to download it through the browser (Firefox), it only downloads 1 GB,
and then downloading fails.
I tried to copy the downloading link and paste it into a download manager,
 
but then Google redirects to an HTML page "ServiceLogin" and downloads it instead.
I also tried to install Google Drive for PC, but it proved to be a piece of malware,
messed up things on my computer, caused me a lot of troubles.

How can I download this large file from Google Drive without this Google Drive for PC?

Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) is the official download page for the Google Drive desktop application.

Comment: I have multiple multi-GB files on Google Drive.  I can download them through the desktop application or the web application.

Comment: I am happy that you can do that, Ramhound. I wish I could do that too.

Comment: I tried the official Google Drive desktop application. It is troublesome. Not only it messed up things on my computer, but it also without asking started to download the entire Google Drive onto my PC, with no apparent way to disable that. I do not like that program and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: What specific download manager did you use? There is the Google Chome App Store that has Chrome apps which work with Google Drive https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/collection/drive_apps  and one of those is Internet Download Manager for Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/internet-download-manager/gejlagkckehbpkfhmiigoceinfaaoaaa

Comment: I use Chrome for web browsing and what I do is to log into my gmail account, go to my Google Drive and then just download from there using the built in download. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive Sync helped me with this. Either you can install the sync and download or sync all files to local pc.

Or

Create a new drive and share the files required to this drive, then sync this drive to local pc using google drive sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python & [GDown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown)
It takes care of the large file warning by Google and should download your file without a problem.